# Submit Eloqua form data via POST request on PHP/Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, eloqua

My client wants Eloqua forms on their website but we have run into issues with spam. I am embedding the export HTML form the client has exported. The exported form has no protection from spam. I plan to enable reCaptcha on the forms to protect from spam which means sending the form data to the server, then submitting the form data to Eloqua.

Am I able to pass the formData to the server and then send that via a POST request to the form action URL?

Comment: Are you talking about https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/Forms/Tasks/EnablingSpamProtectionForForms.htm, or something else? (I can't tell if that will add a recaptcha to the form from their end, or if you are talking about adding it yourself, outside of the scope of functionality that Eloqua offers.)

Comment: Sorry, I am wanting to add it outside of the scope of Eloqua. My client has said there is 'no spam protection' they can employ on their side, so I am looking at adding a reCaptcha separately. So rather than using the standard exported HTML code for the form, I am going to add code to submit the form data via the server.

Comment: _"Am I able to pass the formData to the server and then send that via a POST request to the form action URL?"_ - in theory, yes. But that will of course not stop anyone who knows that URL (or could perhaps guess it), to still submit data to it from elsewhere.

Comment: True, but I think for the purposes of stopping spam it should work. Can I pass the formData into the POST request body? (to replicate submitting a HTML form via the client?)

Comment: Sure, that should be possible. (But if the form provider at some point decides to update their spam-fighting measures, then there might be a slight chance _you_ get blocked then, because getting all the form submissions from your server IP address might look suspicious to begin with - make it look like it was a "bot" ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this issue. I used jQuery to serialise the form data and send it along with the generated reCaptcha token to the web server. My PHP then checks the token against the reCaptcha API and ensures the score is above 0.8. It then sends the formData via POST to the Eloqua form action URL.

The check is done server side and the submissions happens on the server side rather than the client side. The form action URL is also removed from the HTML for extra protection.